# Can I jump to the system album app with fade out animation?

Tags: java, android

I want to jump to the system album. I really jump to the system album app instead of pop up the album to select pictures.

I looked up a lot of information. The closest solution is：

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_GALLERY);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I found that its animation was not what I wanted.

I try this:

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I found that the animation has not changed on some machines, such as HarmonyOS.

Then I try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ComponentName cmp = new ComponentName("xx","xx");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setComponent(cmp);
startActivity(intent);
        
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

However, it can not solve the problem very well, because the package names of the image library are different on different devices.

What better way do I have jump to the system album app with fade out animation?